# Cannot get script to run at startup (tried all the simple answers)

Tags: scripts, startup-applications

I have Ubuntu Desktop 12.04 LTS running great on an older Acer desktop.  I want to use this machine as an in-home server for hosting Minecraft.

The command to start the Minecraft server is `java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar minecraft_server.jar nogui` and that works great when I cd into the correct directory and execute the above.

I created a script to do this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/myuser/minecraft-server1
java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar minecraft_server.jar nogui &
cd /home/myuser/minecraft-server2
java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar minecraft_server.jar nogui &
exit 0
```

I made this .sh file executable, and it too runs great when I start it manually from the terminal.

The problem I'm having is getting these to execute at startup.  I have my user account on this machine to auto login.

I have tried the following:

- Adding the following to "Startup Applications" : `sh /home/myuser/myscript.sh` (Nothing happens on reboot)
- Adding the same to /etc/rc.local (Nothing happens on reboot).  I even tested this one by running `/etc/rc.local` from the terminal, and it executed great.  Just not at boot/auto login
- Added the lines from the script directly to rc.local (Nothing happens on reboot).

I can't help but think that there's something I'm missing.  The script executes great when run manually, but will not run at boot/auto login.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: instead of changing directory then running, run `java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar /home/myuser/minecraft-server1/minecraft_server.jar nogui &` and `java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar /home/myuser/minecraft-server2/minecraft_server.jar nogui &`.  Does that work??

Comment: When I test script /etc/init.d/myscript start it works but it doesn't start on startup

Answer (score 1):

startup and shutdown scripts are usually stored in **/etc/init.d**

Once your script is in the correct location, run the following commands

**chmod +x /etc/init.d/myscript**

**update-rc.d myscript defaults**

Check to see if your script is able to start correctly with the command

**/etc/init.d/myscript start**

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 12.10 if you hit the super key(windows key), and type in "startup applications" and hit enter a window will pop up that will enable you to add a start up program.

Click "add" and in the "Command" field enter the location of your script. That should work.

Comment: Doesnt work with .py scripts

Comment: @SavannahMadison The Python script will need a shebang line and must be marked as executable. Then, it should run the same as any command.

Comment: Tried that.It still doesnt run on startup even though I can manually execute it through the terminal